# Is there a way to convert a numpy array to a dataframe then back to numpy array and still maintain the original shape?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, tensorflow

I loaded 2 numpy arrays from an npz file with the `dtype`; `float64` & `int64`, and one with the shape `(10, 16, 12)`. Within this code, I try to convert from a numpy array to a dataframe (for some necessary operations) but when I convert it back to a numpy array the shape and dtype changes. Is there a way to maintain the original shape and dtype after these conversions?

Code:

```
  signal=np.load(os.path.join(rootdir+"/sample.npz"))['signal']
  phone=np.load(os.path.join(rootdir+"/sample.npz"))['phone']

  
  print('Original Shape: ',signal.shape)
  print('Original Type: ',signal.dtype)

  data= pd.DataFrame(data=[phone, signal]).T

  print(data)

  signal=data[1].to_numpy()  
  print('Shape after: ', signal.shape)
  print('dtype after: ', signal.dtype)
```

Result:

```
Original Shape:  (10, 16, 12)
Original Type:  float64

    0                                                  1
0  42  [[-452.47690531599665, -457.24038307019396, -4...
1  48  [[-494.8202341648372, -489.2340925175253, -500...
2  49  [[-554.1111558403246, -552.5063435313488, -558...
3  60  [[-665.291405811076, -665.1201642439147, -671....
4  22  [[-718.6366745080356, -660.6800599663317, -645...
5  60  [[-867.7087743391858, -864.8980417191354, -863...
6  18  [[-538.0778606068621, -534.2985294058773, -563...
7  45  [[-417.18912118190144, -419.8508768049619, -43...
8  20  [[-597.9549743414366, -580.0114092551831, -561...
9  60  [[-704.9264411271377, -692.1625931932991, -689...

Shape after: (10,)
dtype after: object
```

Comment: Can you put some sample data rows from `phone` and `signal` array

Comment: A dataframe is fundamentally 2d.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Experiment with a simpler 3d array:

```
In [95]: arr = np.arange(24).reshape(3,2,4)
In [96]: df = pd.DataFrame(data=[np.arange(3), arr]).T
In [97]: df
Out[97]: 
   0                                     1
0  0          [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7]]
1  1    [[8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14, 15]]
2  2  [[16, 17, 18, 19], [20, 21, 22, 23]]
In [98]: df.to_numpy()
Out[98]: 
array([[0, array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6, 7]])],
       [1, array([[ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])],
       [2, array([[16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23]])]], dtype=object)
```

Extract just one column/Series:

```
In [99]: df[1].to_numpy()
Out[99]: 
array([array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6, 7]]),
       array([[ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]]),
       array([[16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23]])], dtype=object)
In [100]: np.stack(_)
Out[100]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7]],

       [[ 8,  9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14, 15]],

       [[16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23]]])
In [101]: _.shape
Out[101]: (3, 2, 4)
```

The dataframe has a 2d shape, which also appears in the array:

```
In [102]: _98.shape
Out[102]: (3, 2)
In [103]: df.shape
Out[103]: (3, 2)
```

The column Series is 1d.

Another way to construct that dataframe:

```
In [108]: pd.DataFrame({'x':np.arange(3), 'y':list(arr)})
Out[108]: 
   x                                     y
0  0          [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7]]
1  1    [[8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14, 15]]
2  2  [[16, 17, 18, 19], [20, 21, 22, 23]]
```

I had to convert the 3d array into a list of 2d arrays.

That list can be recovered with (a variant on `Out[99]`):

```
In [109]: df[1].tolist()
Out[109]: 
[array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6, 7]]),
 array([[ 8,  9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14, 15]]),
 array([[16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23]])]
```

Comment: This actually worked. Thank you!!! So basically Numpy -> Dataframe -> List -> Numpy.